# ReactJS - passing data between state and props

Tags: reactjs, state, react-props

I have two components that I use for fetching and rendering data. What I am trying to do is to change the label (and ideally also CSS) of that button in the `CarSearch` component when it is clicked and when the search is done, I want to put there the basic "Search" label.

However, when I click the search button and the search is done, the label "Search" is not set and the label that stays there is still "Filtering...". What is it now changing?

Maybe I am just overcomplicating it and there's a better way to implement it.

```
class Car extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            cars: [],
            searchBtn: 'Searchh'
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('/api/cars')
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({cars: response.data});
                console.log('cars: ', cars);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('CAUGHT IT! -> ', err);
            });
    }
    handleSearch = () => {
        axios.post('/api/cars/search', searchCars)
            .then(response => {
                this.setState({cars: response.data, searchBtn: 'Seach'}) // however, this `searchBtn` will not be passed to `CarSeach`
                console.log('response.data: ', response.data);
            })
    }

    render() {
      return (
        ...
        <CarAddNew />
        <CarSearch 
          onSearch={this.handleSearch} 
          searchBtnLabel={this.state.searchBtn} 
        />
        <CarList cars={this.state.cars} />
      )
    }
}


export default class CarSearch extends Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      searchBtn: props.searchBtnLabel
    }
    handleSearchSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({ searchBtn: 'Filtering...'});
        this.props.onSearch(...) 
    }
    render() {
        return(
          ... search form ...
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-2">
            {this.state.searchBtn}
          </button>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have written it, there are two components (`Car` and `CarSearch`) trying to control the label. The best way to use React is to have a "Golden" source of truth.

There are two ways you can achieve it:

### Parent is the golden source of truth for the state of the search component.

Let your `CarSearch` render the label that is passed to it from `Car`. You can even make the CarSearch component stateless.

```
export default class CarSearch extends Component {
    handleSearchSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.onSearch(...) 
    }
    render() {
        return(
          ... search form ...
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-2">
            {this.props.searchBtnLabel}
          </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Change the `onSearch` function of your `Car` component to explicitly manage the status of search.

```
handleSearch = () => {
this.setState({searchBtn: 'Filtering...'}); 
axios.post('/api/cars/search', searchCars)
     .then(response => {
        this.setState({cars: response.data, searchBtn: 'Search'})
        console.log('response.data: ', response.data);
   })
}
```

### `CarSearch` component handle everything related to Searching.

```
export default class CarSearch extends Component {
    handleSearchSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({searchBtn: 'Filtering...'}); 
        axios.post('/api/cars/search', searchCars)
            .then(response => {
            this.setState({searchBtn: 'Search'});
            this.props.onSearch(response.data);
        })
      }

    }
    render() {
        return(
          ... search form ...
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-sm mx-sm-2">
            {this.state.searchBtn}
          </button>
        )
    }
}
```

Then in your parent component:

```
handleSearch = (data) => {
   this.setState({cars: data})
}
```

### Additional Tips for consideration:

Which one to choose?

It depends on what the component responsibilities are. For e.x. while searching, if you want to reflect that on some other component inside `Car`, for e.x. disable AddCar while it is searching, then Parent should be responsible. If not, Search component can own the state of search.

Another tip, instead of relying on labels to display, I would suggest to maintain the state of the Search component. For e.x. your search can have potentially many states: 
Initial| Searching |Search Failed|Search Success with 0 records| Search successful with more than 0 records.

Making the state of search explicit, lets you control the render in a much more predictable mode.

```
class CarSearch extends Component { 
  state: {
    searchState: 'Initial',
    searchTerm: ''
  }

  onSearch () =>  { 
    this.setState({searchState: 'Searching'})
    axios.post(---)
         .then(this.setState({searchState: 'Success'}))
         .catch(this.setState({searchState: 'Error'}))
  }

  render() {
    // change styles, conditional rendering, show toast etc. based on the state
  }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here, `constructor` method of `CarSearch` component will be called only once after it gets mounted. It'll never be called again. So, what you can do is have [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate)  method in `CarSearch` component and setState when the incoming `searchBtnLabel` prop is different from your present state.

Put the following code after `CarSearch` constructor call.

```js
componentDidUpdate() {
  if (this.props.searchBtnLabel !== this.state.searchBtn) {
    this.setState({ searchBtn: this.props.searchBtnLabel });
  }
}
```

This will solve your problem.

You had mentioned in the comment that filtering phase was not happening. You can fix it like,

```js
handleSearchSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({ searchBtn: 'Filtering...'}, () => {
      this.props.onSearch(...); // setTimeout(() => this.props.onSearch(...), N) where N is milliseconds.
    });
}
```

Explanation: `setState` can accept a callback function which will execute once the state is set successfully. Even after using a callback, if you don't get to see Filtering text, you can use `setTimeout` that I have mentioned as a comment.

Comment: thank you for your answer - I tested it and the thing is that the `Filtering...` phase is now skipped. I tried to also add `setTimeout` to see if the script is just not too fast, but it's not. `Filtering...` is totally skipped now.